# How to Get Google Maps OpeningHoursDetail and Search Features Result in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, google-maps, google-cloud-platform

I currently working on the some Google Map features to include in Flutter app. I have try few days to get the OpeningHoursDetail(open/closed, days and times) and display as Text but it did not displaying any result or showing any error. Anyone know how to solve this issue and get the details? Second issue is the search feature, I unable to get their autocomplete recommendation or get searching result after I typing the address or place name, which part is going wrong? I have enable the Places and Maps SDK for API include all the permission  in Android XML file already. Anyone can please point out or modify the code to show the solution for me, appreciate those help, thank you.

**Code:**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_google_places/flutter_google_places.dart';
import 'package:google_maps_flutter/google_maps_flutter.dart';
import 'package:google_maps_webservice/places.dart';
import 'package:location/location.dart' as LocationManager;

const kGoogleApiKey = "REPLACE_WITH_YOUR_OWN_API_KEY";
GoogleMapsPlaces _places = GoogleMapsPlaces(apiKey: kGoogleApiKey);

class GoogleMapView extends StatefulWidget {
  const GoogleMapView({super.key});

  @override
  State<GoogleMapView> createState() => _GoogleMapViewState();
}

class _GoogleMapViewState extends State<GoogleMapView> {
  late GoogleMapController mapController;
  List<PlacesSearchResult> places = [];
  bool isLoading = false;
  String? errorMessage;
  late TextEditingController _searchController;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _searchController = TextEditingController();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text("Nearby Places"),
        actions: [
          IconButton(
            onPressed: _searchPlaces,
            icon: const Icon(Icons.search),
          ),
        ],
      ),
      body: Stack(
        children: [
          GoogleMap(
            onMapCreated: _onMapCreated,
            initialCameraPosition: const CameraPosition(
              target: LatLng(0, 0), // Default: Center of the world
              zoom: 12,
            ),
            markers: _buildMarkers(),
          ),
          if (isLoading)
            const Center(
              child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
            ),
          if (errorMessage != null)
            Center(
              child: Text(errorMessage!),
            ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  Set<Marker> _buildMarkers() {
    return places.map((place) {
      return Marker(
        markerId: MarkerId(place.placeId),
        position:
            LatLng(place.geometry!.location.lat, place.geometry!.location.lng),
        onTap: () {
          _showPlaceDetails(place);
        },
      );
    }).toSet();
  }

  void _onMapCreated(GoogleMapController controller) {
    setState(() {
      mapController = controller;
      _getCurrentLocation();
    });
  }

  Future<void> _getCurrentLocation() async {
    try {
      LocationManager.LocationData? currentLocation =
          await LocationManager.Location().getLocation();
      LatLng userLocation =
          LatLng(currentLocation.latitude!, currentLocation.longitude!);
      mapController.animateCamera(CameraUpdate.newLatLngZoom(userLocation, 12));
      _getNearbyPlaces(userLocation);
    } catch (e) {
      setState(() {
        errorMessage = "Error getting current location";
      });
    }
  }

  Future<void> _getNearbyPlaces(LatLng userLocation) async {
    setState(() {
      isLoading = true;
      errorMessage = null;
    });

    final location =
        Location(lat: userLocation.latitude, lng: userLocation.longitude);
    final result = await _places.searchNearbyWithRadius(
      location,
      5000, // Radius in meters, adjust as needed
      type: "restaurant", // Specify the desired place type
    );

    setState(() {
      isLoading = false;
      if (result.status == "OK") {
        places = result.results;
      } else {
        errorMessage = result.errorMessage;
      }
    });
  }

Future<void> _searchPlaces() async {
    Prediction? prediction = await PlacesAutocomplete.show(
      context: context,
      apiKey: kGoogleApiKey,
      mode: Mode.overlay,
      components: [
        Component(Component.country, "MY"),
        Component(Component.country, "SG")
      ],
    );

    if (prediction != null) {
      PlacesDetailsResponse details =
          await _places.getDetailsByPlaceId(prediction.placeId!);
      PlaceDetails placeDetails = details.result;
      LatLng location = LatLng(
        placeDetails.geometry!.location.lat,
        placeDetails.geometry!.location.lng,
      );
      mapController.animateCamera(CameraUpdate.newLatLngZoom(location, 15));
      _getNearbyPlaces(location);
    }
  }


  void _showPlaceDetails(PlacesSearchResult place) {
    showModalBottomSheet(
      context: context,
      builder: (BuildContext context) {
        return Container(
          height: 350,
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
          child: Column(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
            children: [
              Text(
                place.name,
                style: const TextStyle(
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                  fontSize: 20.0,
                ),
              ),
              const SizedBox(height: 8.0),
              Text(place.vicinity!),
              const SizedBox(height: 8.0),
              if (place.openingHours != null &&
                  place.openingHours!.periods != null)
                Column(
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                  children: [
                    const Text(
                      'Operation Hours:',
                      style: TextStyle(
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                      ),
                    ),
                    const SizedBox(height: 4.0),
                    for (var period in place.openingHours!.periods)
                      Text(
                        '${_getDayString(period.open!.day)}: ${_formatTime(period.open!.time as TimeOfDay)} - ${_formatTime(period.close!.time as TimeOfDay)}',
                      ),
                  ],
                ),
            ],
          ),
        );
      },
    );
  }

  String _getDayString(int day) {
    switch (day) {
      case DateTime.monday:
        return 'Monday';
      case DateTime.tuesday:
        return 'Tuesday';
      case DateTime.wednesday:
        return 'Wednesday';
      case DateTime.thursday:
        return 'Thursday';
      case DateTime.friday:
        return 'Friday';
      case DateTime.saturday:
        return 'Saturday';
      case DateTime.sunday:
        return 'Sunday';
      default:
        return '';
    }
  }

  String _formatTime(TimeOfDay time) {
    return '${time.hour}:${time.minute.toString().padLeft(2, '0')}';
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

From the code you provided, I noticed that you have other various goals like *fetching nearby places and handling user's current location*. Since your question was specifically about the Autocomplete not working and displaying the opening hours, I focused on those parts and successfully created a Flutter app addressing them.

Here's a breakdown of the key parts of the code:

I have a *"Search Places"* button in my UI which triggers a method named `_handlePressButton` when pressed.

```
@override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return Scaffold(
          key: homeScaffoldKey,
          appBar: AppBar(
            title: const Text("Google Maps Search"),
          ),
          body: Stack(
            children: [
              GoogleMap(
                initialCameraPosition: initialCameraPosition,
                markers: markersList,
                mapType: MapType.normal,
                onMapCreated: (GoogleMapController controller) {
                  mapController = controller;
                },
              ),
              ElevatedButton(
                  onPressed: _handlePressButton, child: const Text("Search Places"))
            ],
          ),
        );
      }
```

Inside that `_handlePressButton` method, like what you did, a `PlacesAutocomplete.show()` method is used to display the search interface. Once the user selects a place from the autocomplete results, the `displayPrediction` method is called.

```
Future<void> _handlePressButton() async {
        Prediction? p = await PlacesAutocomplete.show(
            context: context,
            apiKey: kGoogleApiKey,
            onError: onError,
            mode: _mode,
            language: "en",
            strictbounds: false,
            types: [""],
            decoration: InputDecoration(
                hintText: "Search Places",
                focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
                  borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.green),
                )),
            components: [
              Component(Component.country, "us"),
              Component(Component.country, "ph")
            ]);
        displayPrediction(p!, homeScaffoldKey.currentState);
      }
```

The `displayPrediction` method uses the `GoogleMapsPlaces` class from the `google_maps_webservice` package to get detailed information like location's lat, lng and openingHours. These details were fetched using the `getDetailsByPlaceId` method and display them in an `AlertDialog`.

Instead of trying to extract the daily opening hours manually like your `_getDayString` method, I've used the `openingHours.weedayText` *(which is a list of strings that represents the opening hours for each day of the week)* property from the Places API response.

```
Future<void> displayPrediction(
          Prediction p, ScaffoldState? currentState) async {
        GoogleMapsPlaces places = GoogleMapsPlaces(
            apiKey: kGoogleApiKey,
            apiHeaders: await const GoogleApiHeaders().getHeaders());
    
        PlacesDetailsResponse detail = await places.getDetailsByPlaceId(p.placeId!);
    
        final lat = detail.result.geometry!.location.lat;
        final lng = detail.result.geometry!.location.lng;
        final openingHoursResult =
            detail.result.openingHours?.weekdayText.join("\n");
    
        showDialog(
            context: context,
            builder: (context) {
              return AlertDialog(
                title: Text(detail.result.name),
                content: Column(
                  mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                  children: [
                    Align(
                      alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                      child: Text("Address: $lat, $lng"),
                    ),
                    Align(
                      alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                      child: Column(
                        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                        children: [
                          Text("Opening Hours:"),
                          Text(openingHoursResult ?? "Not available"),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              );
            });
```

With this, things seems to be working fine.
[image]

[image]

Here's my complete code if you want to try on your end.

**main.dart**

```
import 'package:awesome_snackbar_content/awesome_snackbar_content.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_google_places/flutter_google_places.dart';
import 'package:google_api_headers/google_api_headers.dart';
import 'package:google_maps_flutter/google_maps_flutter.dart';
import 'package:google_maps_webservice/places.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        colorScheme: ColorScheme.fromSeed(seedColor: Colors.deepPurple),
        useMaterial3: true,
      ),
      home: const GoogleMapsSearch(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class GoogleMapsSearch extends StatefulWidget {
  const GoogleMapsSearch({super.key, required String title});

  @override
  State<GoogleMapsSearch> createState() => _GoogleMapsSearchState();
}

const kGoogleApiKey = 'YOUR_API_KEY';

final homeScaffoldKey = GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>();

class _GoogleMapsSearchState extends State<GoogleMapsSearch> {
  static const CameraPosition initialCameraPosition = CameraPosition(
    target: LatLng(37.42796, -122.08574),
    zoom: 14.0,
  );

  Set<Marker> markersList = {};

  late GoogleMapController mapController;

  final Mode _mode = Mode.overlay;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      key: homeScaffoldKey,
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text("Google Maps Search"),
      ),
      body: Stack(
        children: [
          GoogleMap(
            initialCameraPosition: initialCameraPosition,
            markers: markersList,
            mapType: MapType.normal,
            onMapCreated: (GoogleMapController controller) {
              mapController = controller;
            },
          ),
          ElevatedButton(
              onPressed: _handlePressButton, child: const Text("Search Places"))
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  Future<void> _handlePressButton() async {
    Prediction? p = await PlacesAutocomplete.show(
        context: context,
        apiKey: kGoogleApiKey,
        onError: onError,
        mode: _mode,
        language: "en",
        strictbounds: false,
        types: [""],
        decoration: InputDecoration(
            hintText: "Search Places",
            focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
              borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.green),
            )),
        components: [
          Component(Component.country, "us"),
          Component(Component.country, "ph")
        ]);
    displayPrediction(p!, homeScaffoldKey.currentState);
  }

  void onError(PlacesAutocompleteResponse response) {
    ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(SnackBar(
      elevation: 0,
      behavior: SnackBarBehavior.floating,
      backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
      content: AwesomeSnackbarContent(
        title: 'Message',
        message: response.errorMessage!,
        contentType: ContentType.failure,
      ),
    ));
  }

  Future<void> displayPrediction(
      Prediction p, ScaffoldState? currentState) async {
    GoogleMapsPlaces places = GoogleMapsPlaces(
        apiKey: kGoogleApiKey,
        apiHeaders: await const GoogleApiHeaders().getHeaders());

    PlacesDetailsResponse detail = await places.getDetailsByPlaceId(p.placeId!);

    final lat = detail.result.geometry!.location.lat;
    final lng = detail.result.geometry!.location.lng;
    final openingHoursResult =
        detail.result.openingHours?.weekdayText.join("\n");

    showDialog(
        context: context,
        builder: (context) {
          return AlertDialog(
            title: Text(detail.result.name),
            content: Column(
              mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
              children: [
                Align(
                  alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                  child: Text("Address: $lat, $lng"),
                ),
                Align(
                  alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                  child: Column(
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                    children: [
                      Text("Opening Hours:"),
                      Text(openingHoursResult ?? "Not available"),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          );
        });

    markersList.clear();
    markersList.add(Marker(
        markerId: const MarkerId("0"),
        position: LatLng(lat, lng),
        infoWindow: InfoWindow(
          title: detail.result.name,
        )));

    setState(() {});

    mapController
        .animateCamera(CameraUpdate.newLatLngZoom(LatLng(lat, lng), 14.0));
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, it is worked. Appreciate your help!

Comment: @ICanDone if you think this answer solved your issue, feel free to mark this as accepted.